# How do I define operator >> (istream &, ...) for a standard type that lacks a pre-defined operator without extending namespace `std`?

Tags: c++, namespaces, deserialization, c++-chrono, boost-program-options

Apparently it's Undefined Behaviour to add ([almost](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)) anything to the `std` namespace.

I'm using C++14 which has no `std::chrono::parse()` (C++20 only) but I need to deserialise values of type `std::chrono::milliseconds` (a specialisation of `std::chrono::duration`) from an `istream`.

Although this works, I can't find any exceptions that allow this to not be UB:

```
namespace std {
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream & is, std::chrono::milliseconds & ms) {
    std::string s;
    is >> s;
    ms = std::chrono::milliseconds(std::stoi(s));
    return is;
}
}
```

Since neither of these two parameter types are *my* types, I'm not sure how I'd safely define this operator outside of the `std` namespace.

Note that the operator will be called deep within `Boost::program_options` so I don't think I can define the operator in my own namespace and then use `using my_ns::operator>>` because the scope of that `using` declaration won't extend into the `program_options` scope.

### How I Ended Up Here

As a user of `Boost::program_options` I have a particular configuration variable that I read from a configuration file that is stored as a `std::chrono::milliseconds` value:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds period;
po::options_description config_only_opts;
config_only_opts.add_options()
    ("control.period", po::value<std::chrono::milliseconds>(&period), "Specify the period in milliseconds");

// ...

auto istream = ifstream("config.cfg");
po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_config_file(istream, config_file_opts, false), vm);
```

According to the `Boost::program_options` documentation, it is possible to deserialise values from the config file for types that have an `operator >> (istream &, ...)` function defined.

Without the extention to `std` mentioned above, I end up with this kind of compiler error:

```
/home/david/opt/boost-1.69/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::detail::deduce_target_char_impl<boost::detail::deduce_character_type_later<std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> > > >’:
/home/david/opt/boost-1.69/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:270:89:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::deduce_target_char<std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> > >’
/home/david/opt/boost-1.69/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:407:92:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::lexical_cast_stream_traits<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> > >’
/home/david/opt/boost-1.69/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:468:15:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::lexical_converter_impl<std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’
/home/david/opt/boost-1.69/include/boost/lexical_cast/try_lexical_convert.hpp:201:44:   required from ‘bool boost::conversion::detail::try_lexical_convert(const Source&, Target&) [with Target = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> >; Source = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/home/david/opt/boost-1.69/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:41:60:   required from ‘Target boost::lexical_cast(const Source&) [with Target = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> >; Source = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/home/david/opt/boost-1.69/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:92:36:   required from ‘void boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<charT> >&, T*, long int) [with T = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> >; charT = char]’
/home/david/opt/boost-1.69/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:184:21:   required from ‘void boost::program_options::typed_value<T, charT>::xparse(boost::any&, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<charT> >&) const [with T = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> >; charT = char]’
/home/david/myproj/Config.cpp:208:1:   required from here
/home/david/opt/boost-1.69/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:243:13: error: static assertion failed: Target type is neither std::istream`able nor std::wistream`able
             BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((result_t::value || boost::has_right_shift<std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, T >::value),
             ^
```

Comment: `operator >>` doesn't normally need to be in the `std` namespace or any other namespace. If you can add a few details on how you wound up in this position we might be able to get you out of it.

Comment: @user4581301 I've added some background as requested - thank you.

Comment: I think the issue is primarily driven by the fact that I want to _store_ the result in a `std::chrono::milliseconds` rather than anything special about the serialisation format. Perhaps I should just extract the value via a pure integer and then use it to initialise the `period` value after the parsing has completed.

Answer (score 5):

I would not recommend adding that function even if the standard allowed the operator to be overloaded. It's not a generic way to read a `std::chrono::milliseconds` from a `std::istream`. What you have is your application's own way of reading such an object from a `std::istream`.

I recommend adding a function in your application's own `namespace`.

```
namespace MyApp
{
   std::istream& readChronoMilliSeconds(std::istream& is, std::chrono::milliseconds & ms)
   {
      std::string s;
      is >> s;
      ms = std::chrono::milliseconds(std::stoi(s));
      return is;
   }
}
```

Comment: I can see how such a function is useful, but unfortunately `Boost::program_options` requires an `operator>>` for the types that it deserialises. Do you think it better that I simply load the config option as a pure integer instead? Seems unfortunate because I have other custom types that I load from the config file (enums, structs, etc) but they are my own types so I can easily define `operator>>(istream, ...)` for them. Maybe I should wrap `std::chrono::milliseconds` with my own custom class and then use that for deserialisation?

Comment: @davidA, that last statement makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using fancy types for input parameter is fooling yourself because input parameters generally are nothing else than numbers, strings or lists of them.

What I recommend is to take a proper integer value and convert internally to milliseconds.

```
int period_in_ms = 0;
...
config_only_opts.add_options()
    ("control.period_in_ms", po::value<int>(&period_in_ms), "Specify the period in milliseconds");
...
auto period = std::chrono::milliseconds(period_in_ms);
```

You can use the "notify" mechanism in Boost.ProgramOptions to update the value of `period` in-place but it is not worth the trouble.

If you want to input the parameter in a certain format (e.g. finish with "ms", as in "100ms") then take a `value<std::string>` and make the conversion/parsing.